# Same "name" for Onblur and id cause ambiguity

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making this form that will have Ajax and I wanted to use javascript for validation on client side. However I encounter a problem when I put id name and onblur fnc name the same:

```
<label>Title*:</label>

<?php 
echo '<input type="text" id="title1" value = "" onblur="title1(this.value)"/> <span id="err1"> </span> <p></p>';
?>
```

Basically Ajax won't work because my fnc name is the same as id name. I'm just wondering why it caused ambiguity since onblur and id need diff parameters.

Comment: First, why would you use the same names?  Second, post the code for your function.

Comment: JavaScript, what are you doing in that HTML! Get out! Go, shoo!

Comment: Seriously though, keep your HTML in .html files, CSS in .css files and JS in .js files.

Comment: I'm only putting the fnc name (onblur = JSFnc()), not the the JS fnc  inside HTML. Maybe im missing your point?

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers automatically make elements with an ID be properties of the global `window` object. To circumvent this, it is important to declare them explicitly. Try this:

```
var title1 = function(val) {
    // function body
}
```

This basically forces the browser to keep `title1` as a variable and not a reference to the element.

Comment: This a good explanation why this is happening, but shouldn't the ultimate solution be to change the name of the function? What happens if the same element needs to take action on two different events? You can't have two functions with the same name in the same scope. I would suggest something like `title1_onBlur` for the function name.

Comment: I just wanted to know the reason why it cause ambiguity, but I did change the fnc name